# to find the smallest value of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Find the smallest natural number n such that there exist infinitely
many solutions to [a1,a2...,an]/a1+a2+...+an= k , for all k ∈ N.
Here [a , b]=LCM(a , b).
I tried it and it seems very odd as we need to find p/q=k[p and q having no common factor] and this works for every K belonging to N. Can anyone help me how this is possible?

Comment: It is really hard to read Please use MathJax

Comment: I dont understand how this is possible can anyone help me think how can this be possible?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore can you please specify what is the problem?

Comment: E.g., $\frac{[1,2,3]}{1+2+3}=1$, so there may be an emerging common factor

Comment: yup but how is it possible for every K

Comment: is there any example where this case  happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $$\frac{[1,2k,2k+1]}{1+2k+(2k+1)}=\frac{2k(2k+1)}{4k+2}=k, $$
so $n=3$ is certainly big enough. Can you see why $n<3$ does not work for all $k$?

Comment: yes thanks i got it :)